# In Robot Framwork how to set value of variable based on some condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework

If there is a variable `${var}` I want to set its value to 0 if its current value is None otherwise leave the current value unchanged.
I understand it should be very easy but some how I am having trouble in verifying the recipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Set variable if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If), and give the current value as the second value:

```
${var}=  Set variable if  $var is None  0  ${var}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the keyword Set Variable If

```
 ${Var}=    Set Variable If   '${Current_Value}'=='None'     0    ${Current_Value}
```

Comment: This does the same thing whether the current value is the string `"None"` or the value is the python value `None`. I think the OP only wants to set the variable if the current value is the python value `None`.